# Laravel 4 and PostgreSQL installed on remote server

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-4

I've installed Laravel 4 on a windows machine with XAMPP and PostgreSQL on a virtual machine (Ubuntu).
I also edited below files on PostgreSQL machine (ubuntu) to work correctly:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

**In a raw php:** on my Windows machine I can connect to PostgreSQL database on the remote machine by the below code and everything is okay:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=192.168.56.101 port=5432 dbname=gis user=gisuser password=mypass");
$sql="CREATE TABLE users (id varchar(5),name varchar(20),PRIMARY KEY(id))";
pg_exec($dbconn, $sql) or die(pg_errormessage());
```

now users table was created in my PostgreSQL database.

**But in Laravel:** I can't connect with the same config. I setup everything in database.php and when I run the following artisan command:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

the following error occured in command line:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

migrate:install [--database[="..."]]
```

Can anyone please help me to connect to my remote PostgreSQL server via Laravel 4 on my Windows  machine?

Comment: May it have to do which config environment you are running and that you have edited the wrong database.php file? Have you specified any environment in /bootstrap/start.php?

Comment: Oops! You're right John. My local database config override the main config, so Laravel always use the wrong configuration for pgsql connection. Thank you so much @JohnP